# Big list is not writing in txt document python

Tags: python

```
def number_gen():
    n = 0
    repet = int(input("How many number do you want to generate :"))
    for i in range(repet):
        x = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(24))
        y = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(6))
        z = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(27))
        writinge = (f"{x}.{y}.{z}")
        with open('C:\\Users\\bad\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\Number-Generator\\Number.txt', 'w') as handle:
            handle.write(writinge+"\n")
            handle.close()
        n+=1
        print(f'{n}|{repet} Generated --- {x}.{y}.{z}')'
```

1. So the thing is that it is not saving all of it only 1 number
2. sorry for the bad order of the code idk how it is working

Answer (score 2):

You're repeatedly reopening the file with the `"w"` flag, which empties the file. (You could also repeatedly open the file with the `"a"` (append) flag, but that's far less performant).

Instead, open the file *around* the loop, only one time. Also, you don't need to `.close()` it when using `with`.

Also, DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself); make the random characters a variable:

```
import random
import string

characters = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits


def number_gen():
    n = 0
    repet = int(input("How many number do you want to generate :"))
    with open("C:\\Users\\bad\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\Number-Generator\\Number.txt", "w") as handle:
        for i in range(repet):
            x = "".join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(24))
            y = "".join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(6))
            z = "".join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(27))
            writinge = f"{x}.{y}.{z}"
            handle.write(writinge + "\n")
            n += 1
        print(f"{n}|{repet} Generated --- {x}.{y}.{z}")
```

Comment: thanks you very much